# Bugsnag notice error undefined is not an object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, undefined, nuxt.js, bugsnag

I am using bugsnag to trace error. My project using nuxtjs, In recently, I often see my bugsnap show a erorr

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 't.$options')
```

But it is only show the page that has error, not show line code has error, it make me difficult to reproduce and fix it. Show anyone has experience can help me. Thank you

Comment: Search your code for `t.$options`. The error suggests that `t` is undefined.

Comment: I try to search but all project doesn't exist any `t.$options `. I guess this code is after compile .